# FileUpload / Input File I can't upload .exe file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, file-upload

I tried using

```
<input type="file" accept=".zip" ID="FileUpload1" Style="display: none" runat="server" onchange="upload()" />
```

and

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" onchange="upload()"/>
```

## Client SIDE

```
function upload() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('<%= hideButton.ClientID %>');
    btn.click();
}

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hideButton" Text="" Style="display: none;" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

## Server SIDE

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

but no one is working.
I can import .doc / .rar / .zip but when i select a .exe or a .zip who contain a .exe i got this
[image]

When i debug the code and try to upload a .exe file, the UploadButton_Click is not called. Is there something to do in the web.config to allow the application to deal with .exe file?
I found nothing about this issue, it looks like the web app doesn't to deal with .exe file or maybe the browser too. (I try on IE and Chrome)

Edit:

1)So i went to the firewall and deactivate everything and try again KO

2)I went tot the windows defender firewall settings and everything is check about to allow chrome to communicate with the firewall

Comment: If you are not using your own server but a hosted solution, the provider probably blocks potentially dangerous files. Probably a firewall or virus scanner blocking the request.

Comment: For the moment, i am working locally but i will check if the firewall or virus scanner is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was about the size of my .exe file.
I update my web.config file and update the maxRequestLength.